# Github Actions: check steps status

Tags: github-actions

I have in my job for CI some steps which can throw an error. I don't want restart workflow on every step with error and want to go to the last step that checks those steps and complete this job as fail.
But I can't get status info previously steps.

```
name: CI
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Step 1
        id: hello
        run: <any> 
        continue-on-error: true
      - name: Step 2
        id: world
        run: <any> 
        continue-on-error: true
      - name: Check on failures
        if: job.steps.hello.status == failure() || job.steps.world.status == failure()
        run: exit 1
```

When I use next constructions in "if" or "run" then will get: steps -> {}, job.steps -> null.

How can I get status information?

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: "When I use next constructions in "if" or "run" ...". Could you try rephrasing it?

Comment: for example:
`- name: Check on failures
   run: ${{ toJson(steps) }}  ${{ toJson(job.steps) }}`
then I will get `{} null`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**Update**: The [`steps` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#steps-context) now contains detail about the execution of each step by default. Using the `outcome` property of each step we can check the result of its execution.

```yaml
name: CI
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Step 1
        id: hello
        run: <any> 
        continue-on-error: true
      - name: Step 2
        id: world
        run: <any> 
        continue-on-error: true
      - name: Check on failures
        if: steps.hello.outcome != 'success' || steps.world.outcome != 'success'
        run: exit 1
```

**Original answer**
Looking at the documentation for the steps context, it doesn't look like it contains any information about the step other than `outputs`. These must be explicitly defined by steps. That is why the steps context is empty `{}`.

https://help.github.com/en/articles/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#steps-context

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, there is no default status for a step that can be accessed. The solution involves manually defining a status output variable from each step.

```
name: CI
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Step 1
        id: hello
        run: echo ::set-output name=status::failure
        continue-on-error: true
      - name: Step 2
        id: world
        run: echo ::set-output name=status::success
        continue-on-error: true
      - name: Dump steps context
        env:
          STEPS_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(steps) }}
        run: echo "$STEPS_CONTEXT"
      - name: Check on failures
        if: steps.hello.outputs.status == 'failure' || steps.world.outputs.status == 'failure'
        run: exit 1
```

This creates the following context output and the job fails.

```
{
  "hello": {
    "outputs": {
      "status": "failure"
    }
  },
  "world": {
     "outputs": {
      "status": "success"
    }
  }
}
```

https://help.github.com/en/articles/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputs
https://help.github.com/en/articles/development-tools-for-github-actions#set-an-output-parameter-set-output

Comment: Thank you, @peterevans!
I simpled it and set only "success" at the end of my "run". 
So for me enough:
`if: steps.hello.outputs.status != 'success' || steps.world.outputs.status != 'success'`

Comment: Update 2020:
As other answers mentioned, it's no longer necessary (if ever was, IDK), to explicitly set the output. You just need: 1. to set an `id` on your step, and 2. to call `steps.<step id>.outcome`. Reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#steps-context

Please, @peterevans, update the answer to add such information.

Comment: What if the step was rejected manually by clicking the reject button? In this case the step has status `failure`. How to distinguish this behavior from the real failure?

Answer (score 8):

You can get status using [setps.STEPNAME.outcome property](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#steps-context), associated to a check of success() or failure()

```
name: CI
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Step 1
        id: hello
        run: <any> 
        continue-on-error: true
      - name: Step 2
        id: world
        run: <any> 
        continue-on-error: true
      - name: Check on failures
        if: (${{ success() }} || ${{ failure() }}) && (${{ steps.hello.outcome }} == 'failure' || ${{ steps.world.outcome }} == 'failure')
        run: exit 1
```

Comment: Why do you need this: `(${{ success() }} || ${{ failure() }})` ?

Comment: it is required to run the step undepending the previous ones has been in success or in error

Comment: Would this differ to `always()`
?

Comment: @BF99 `always` also runs on cancellations.

Answer (score 4):

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    env:
      DOCKER_PASS: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASS }} 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    - name: script
      id: test1
      continue-on-error: true
      run: |
        ls -l sadasd
        
    - name: script
      id: sync
      continue-on-error: true
      run: |
        ls -l
    - name: Dump steps context
      env:
        STEPS_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(steps) }}
      run: echo "$STEPS_CONTEXT"
```

the output

```
Run echo "$STEPS_CONTEXT"
{
  "test1": {
    "outputs": {},
    "outcome": "failure",
    "conclusion": "success"
  },
  "sync": {
    "outputs": {},
    "outcome": "success",
    "conclusion": "success"
  }
}
```

so could use step:

```
    - name: sync run
      id: sync
      continue-on-error: true
      run: |
        .....
    - name: after_success
      run: |
        ...
      if: steps.sync.outcome  == 'success'
    - name: after_failure
      run: |
        ...
      if: steps.sync.outcome != 'success'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using somewhat similar to @peterevans suggested earlier but leveraging the shell exit for a command and `set +e` flag:

```
name: CI
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Step 1
        id: hello
        run: |
          set +e
          ./my-script.sh
          echo ::set-output name=exit_status::failure
      - name: Step 2
        id: world
        run:
          set +e
          python3 ./my-script.py
          echo ::set-output name=exit_status::$?
      - name: Check on failures
        if: steps.hello.outputs.exit_status != 0 | steps.world.outputs.exit_status != 0
        run: exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue today and solved by using a condition:

```
name: CI
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Step 1
        id: hello
        run: <any> 
        if: ${{ failure() ||  success() }}
      - name: Step 2
        id: world
        run: <any> 
        if: ${{ failure() ||  success() }}
```

In the end:

- All steps are executed
- The job `myjob` will fail if any step fails

This is similar to Azure DevOps [succeededOrFailed() condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Happy workflowing!